# Deploy simple server using Flask on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I'm using this Python code to see if I can view the simple AWS server however, I'm still not able to load the webpage properly.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "It works!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=80, host='0.0.0.0')
```

In AWS, inbound:

```
HTTP TCP port 80 with a source of: 0.0.0.0/0
SSH TCP port 22 with a source of: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Outbound - everything is allowed.

I'm seeing no errors on terminal when I start the program. The console says `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` so I'm trying to load `http://ubuntu@ec2-IPADDRESS.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000`

Answer (score 1):

[Flask defaults to binding to 127.0.0.1:5000](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L828-L834).

If you're trying to access http://ubuntu@ec2-IPADDRESS.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000 , you'll need to have port 5000 opened in the inbound firewall rules and bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I did a custom TCP rule for port 5000 but also opened all TCP for all ports but it's still not loading.

Comment: @user1883614 I edited the post to take the binding host into account.

Comment: added that in my post above, same issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use port 80 for your web application. Let it run on default port then host your web application by mod_wsgi or uWSGI... Check the deployment options here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/ .

Imo: better if you deploy your application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Give me a shout if you need a sample project.